# Are there Thunderbolt drive enclosures?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware, external-connection, mac

The only Thunderbolt hard-drive adapter that I've found so far is part of the Seagate GoFlex system.

I am surprised no one seems to offer drive enclosures with Thunderbolt yet.

At issue here is fast external hard-drives for Mac Book and Mac mini systems at a reasonable price.

Thunderbolt to USB 3 would suffice but I cannot find that yet either.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I know that on Server Fault, shopping recommendations are off-topic as per the [FAQ]; may I suggest http://apple.stackexchange.com/ as Thunderbolt is primarily used in Apple devices.

Comment: Not shopping. Asking technically.

Comment: You might miss how 'new' thunderbolt still is. Apple had it exclusively for about a year. Other systems are just slowly getting the new interface.  -- As for other manufacturers: I am not sure how many others there are, but seagate is not the only one (e.g. see http://www.promise.com/storage/raid_series.aspx?region=en-global&m=192&rsn1=40&rsn3=60 )